# How can I ensure good test-coverage of my big Python proejct

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, python-coverage

I have a very large python project with a very large test suite. Recently we have decided to quantify the quality of our test-coverage.

I'm looking for a tool to automate the test coverage report generation. Ideally I'd like to have attractive, easy to read reports but I'd settle for less attractive reports if I could make it work quickly.

I've tried Nose, which is not good enough: It is incompatible with distribute / setuptools' namespace package feature. Unfortunately nose coverage will never work for us since we make abundant use of this feature. That's a real shame because Nose seems to work really nicely in Hudson (mostly)

As an alternative, I've heard that there's a way to do a Python coverage analysis in Eclipse, but I've not quite locked-down the perfect technique.

Any suggestions welcome!

FYI we use Python 2.4.4 on Windows XP 32bit

Comment: I tried reproducing this problem and could not.  Salim, if you want help with it, drop me a line.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage)?  It underlies "nose coverage", but can be run perfectly well outside of nose if you need to.

If you run your tests with (hypothetically) `python run_my_tests.py`, then you can measure coverage with `coverage run run_my_tests.py`, then get HTML reports with `coverage html`.

From your description, I'm not sure what problem you had with nose, especially whether it was a nose issue, or a coverage.py issue.  Provide some more details, and I'm sure we can work through them.

Answer (score 1):

Ned has already mentioned his excellent coverage.py module.

If the problem you're having is something nose specific, you might want to consider using another test runner. I've used [py.test](http://codespeak.net/py/dist/test/) along with the [pytest_coverage](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-coverage/0.3) plugin that lets you generate coverage statistics. It also has a [pytest_nose](http://codespeak.net/py/trunk/test/plugin/nose.html) plugin to help you migrate.

However, I don't understand exactly what the problem you're facing is. Can you elaborate a little on the "distribute / setuptools' namespace package feature" you mentioned? I'm curious to know what the problem is.

Comment: We use the namespace packages feature of setuptools which allows multiple eggs to provide stuff in a signle namespace, so for example if myproduct_foo_1.0.egg might provide the namespace myproduct and myproduct.foo, and myproduct_bar_1.0.egg would provide the namespace myproduct.bar. When I try to do a coverage analysis on myproduct the coverage tool needs to detect which of the two eggs actually contains the source of every relevant module. At the moment nose / cover.py seems to be doing it wrong.

Comment: Salim, I would love to fix coverage.py to get this right.  Do you have sample I can try myself?

Comment: BTW: I added a coverage.py ticket for this problem: http://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issue/75/namespace-packages-break-coveragepys-ability-to-find-source